# How to REDIRECT a web Page for every ten seconds

Tags: html, http, redirect, header, metaprogramming

In simple there is any way to redirect a page for every ten seconds in PHP

Comment: wrong tags, and I really can't understand the issue...

Comment: why would you want to do **that**?

Comment: A simple method to show newer data without using ajax?

Comment: Palantir is right. Your question indicates an HTML problem, but you tagged it php and MySQL... And redirecting every 10 seconds??? You really need to rephrase and retag.

Comment: You should have kept your initial description (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1326829/list#revb2eddb5a-f948-484e-9a20-72d2914d82c3). The information, that you want to step through a play list, is quite fundamental, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Using HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

Using JavaScript:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, 10000)
```

These will reload only the current page.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need PHP for that. HTML will be enough. If you redirect to a page that has the same meta tag defined all the time you will have your "redirect-every-10-seconds".

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; url=http://www.example.com/">
</head>
<body>
     page body
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "refresh: 10; url={$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" );
```

Comment: *Refresh* is not an official HTTP header field. So I doubt that it’s supported widely.

Comment: All usual browsers support it. Maybe it's not in the papers, but is a defacto standard.

Comment: "usual" browsers support a lot of things that are "none standard" - but for that very reason you shouldn't use them