# how to call a function in PHP after 10 seconds of the page load (Not using HTML)

Tags: php

Is there any way to call a function 10 seconds after the page load in PHP. (Not using HTML.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326829/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-for-every-ten-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. Edited from randell's answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
  {
    setTimeout(function()    {   $('#some_id').load('index.php');    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

Thanks to randell

Answer (score 22):

**PHP is a server side scripting language.**  If you need to check if something has loaded already in the client side, **you will need a client-side scripting language like JavaScript**.

**You might need to use jQuery for your purpose** to simplify things.

> jQuery is a
> slow JavaScript
> Library that simplifies HTML document
> traversing, event handling, animating,
> and Ajax interactions for rapid web
> development. jQuery is designed to
> change the way that you write
> JavaScript.

First, download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  In the head tag of your HTML, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
$(document).ready( function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#some_id').load('index.php'); 
    }, 10000); 
}); 
</script>
```

In the body of your HTML, add this:

```
<div id="some_id"></div>
```

Comment: i think your code contains wrong syntax. will you please check it out.. apologize if i am wrong randell..

Answer (score 13):

Not really, no. 10 seconds after your page loaded is (at least) 10 seconds after your PHP script finished, i.e. *it is no longer running* (apart from tricks that try keeping the connection open, which I don't think will work for a time as long as 10 seconds)!

Therefore, you either need to schedule a `cron` job on the server side to fire in 10 seconds, or you need a callback from the website, using AJAX.

Comment: The OP actually asked how to call a function *during* page load, not afterwards.

Comment: ah OK, I have edited your question to reflect this, but left the original intact otherwise not all the responses will make much sense!

Comment: Ok, forget 10 sec, How can I execute a query *(using php, not js)*, exactly when all of the page loaded? (for your information, that query is for increasing the number of viewed, and my purpose is: increasing the speed of page loading)

Comment: @Shafizadeh XHR callback. jQuery for instance makes this very easy. You *need* a client-side callback to call the server — there’s no other way: as I’ve said in my answer, by the time the site has loaded, the PHP script has finished executing, and the server-side PHP script has no way of knowing when the client finished loading the page anyway.

Comment: Well, If JS be deactivate on a user's device *(browser)*, then query does not execute, right?

Comment: @Shafizadeh That is correct. There isn’t really a way around this. But I’m not sure I understand your problem anyway: why not just increase the view counter in the PHP script directly? It won’t affect page loading.

Answer (score 11):

If I interpret your question as "My page takes a long time to generate, now can I call a PHP function every 10 seconds while it generates" then there are several ways you can approach this...

### Time your loop, do something after 10 seconds of work...

```
$nexttick=time()+10;
$active=true;

while ($active)
{
    if (time()>=$nexttick)
    {
        my_tick_function();
        $nexttick=time()+10;
    }

    //now do some useful processing
    $active=do_some_work();
}
```

It's possible to use a technique like this to implement a progress meter for long running operations, by having your "tick" function output some javascript to update the HTML representing a progress meter.

### Using pcntl_alarm...

Alternatively, if you have the [Process Control](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) support enabled in your build of PHP, you might be able to use [pcntl_alarm](http://php.net/pcntl_alarm) to call a signal handler after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

### Using ticks...

You can use the [declare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php) construct along with [register_tick_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) to have the PHP engine call your function every x 'ticks'. From the manual:

> A tick is an event that occurs for
> every N low-level tickable statements
> executed by the parser within the
> declare block. The value for N is
> specified using ticks=N  within the
> declare blocks's directive section.

Comment: I think this is the best response based on what the user may have really been asking (or at leas my interpretation). Just out of curiosity, though, what is the purpose of setting `$active = true` and then to `do_some_work()`? Will the script actually stop running the `do_some_work` function to return to the if loop?

Comment: That's just to illustrate you'll keep looping until you decide there's no more work to do.

Answer (score 8):

This seems weird idea but maybe it's what you are looking for if you want to do it in PHP without touching HTML/JS:

```
<?php
your_website_here();

flush(); //this sends the output to the client. You may also need ob_flush();
sleep(10); //wait 10 seconds

your_func_here();
?>
```

The above is preety OK in theory, but in practice it will result in VERY memory consuming app. So be warned.

Comment: Anytime out issues if this were used for say, 5 minutes?

Answer (score 4):

if you mean after the page has loaded you will need to use javascript/ajax/jquery to do so.

Comment: sorry brain.. i am a newbie... will you explain how using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do it within the same PHP script, the cleanest way would be a [fork](http://php.net/pcntl_fork).

Or if that's not possible, here's a really bad hackish way of doing it:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(1);

page_output_stuff();
// ...

flush();
sleep(10);
do_something_after_script();
?>
```

If you're doing this to output stuff to the user after a delay, the above *can* be made to work but it's a really ugly way of doing it. Just use AJAX instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do it with PHP, except maybe using some crontab / loop with sleep() and file_get_contents(). Or use javascript/ajax as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Php is a servide scripting language, and can't detect if the page is loaded or not. so you have to use client side script javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The closest think I can think of is :

Once your script has finish to execute, it saves an entry in a databases with the time. Then, a daemon (cron style) execute every second each instruction in the databases that is older than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, to be notified at each hit my resume got.
With flush() after all data sent then the DB and mail operations: the page on the client is fully rendered but the downloading progress bar is still present until the script is fully terminated.

I wanted to keep the whole stuff server-side (to allow the generated HTML file to be cleanly usable offline without giving errors) so JS wasn't an option.

I eventually ended simply appending a line with parameters to a text file, add a cron job every minute that compares this file size with the latest sent version and this bash script handles all the lenghty functions while the 9k page still loads and renders in a fraction of a second.

Unfortunately this method still has a up to 1 minute delay but still simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
FLOG=/home/web/traceur/cvaccess.txt

if [ -e $FLOG ]; then
    if [ ! -e $FLOG.sent ]; then touch $FLOG.sent; fi;
    SENT_LINES=$(wc -l $FLOG.sent | cut -d " " -f 1)

    # No disk write if no new-data
    if [ $(wc -l $FLOG | cut -d " " -f 1) -gt $SENT_LINES ]; then
        cp -f $FLOG $FLOG.intr
        NEW_LINES=$(wc -l $FLOG.intr | cut -d " " -f 1)
        TO_SEND=$(( $NEW_LINES - $SENT_LINES ))
        tail -n $TO_SEND $FLOG.intr > $FLOG.diff

        mailx -s "Nouvelle consultation du CV" -r "HAL <hal@jmd-tech.com>" jmarodon@jmd-tech.com < $FLOG.diff
        rm $FLOG.diff
        mv -f $FLOG.intr $FLOG.sent
    fi
fi
```

And the page is at:
http://www.jmd-tech.com/cv-julien-marodon.html, the PHP code is nothing more than those 3 lines at the end of the previously plain HTML file:

```
<?php
// Enregistrement log
$ligne=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\t".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]."\t".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."\t".date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$fic=fopen("/home/web/traceur/cvaccess.txt","a");
if ($fic) { fwrite($fic,$ligne."\n"); fclose($fic); }
?>
```

If i wanted to make a near-instant (<1s) or a 10 second delay version, i think the way to go would be using a daemon instead of a cron job and some kind of inter-process communication, probably a listening socket which the PHP script would fsockopen() for sending data and closing (fast), then the daemon proceeds by himself with lenghty operations.