# Can a PHP script be scheduled to run at a specific time or after a specific amount of time has expired?

Tags: php, android, timer, cron, alarm

I am writing a social cloud game for Android and using PHP on the server.  Almost all aspects of the game will be user or user-device driven, so most of the time the device will send a request to the server and the server will, in turn, send a response to the device.  Sometimes the server will also send out push messages to the devices, but generally in response to one user's device contacting the server.

There is one special case, however, where a user can set a "timer" and, after the given time has elapsed, the server needs to send the push messages to all of the devices.  One way to do this would be to keep the timer local to the user's device and, once it goes off, send the signal to the server to send the push messages.  However, there were several reasons why I did not want to do it this way.  For instance, if the user decides not to play anymore or loses the game, the timer should technically remain in play.

I looked around for a method in PHP that would allow me to do something like this, but all I came up with were alarms, which are *not* what I need.  I also thought of cron jobs and, indeed, they have been recommended for similar situations on this and other forums, but since this is not a recurring event but, rather, a one time event to take place at an arbitrary point in time, I did not know that a cron job is what I want either.

My current best solution involves a cron job that runs once a second and checks to see if one of these events is to occur in the next second and, if so, sends out the push messages.  Is this the proper way to handle this situation, or is there a better tool out there that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: cron job or a daemon, or a more appropriate language than php

Comment: "more appropriate language than php"? you can set a cron job with PHP, so it's hardly an inappropriate method

Comment: The minimum intervals for running cronjob is a minute, you can't execute something every second. I don't think its a good idea to run it every second, but if you do find that solution to suit you, you'll have to create another script that simply `while(true){system('php /path/to/file &'); sleep(1);}`

Comment: @Dagon: well, I'm more versed in C/C++ than anything else, so a daemon might be more what I was looking for.  In that case, I could have a queue of these timers in sorted order and wait on some kind of event to be triggered for the amount of time until the first item in the queue.  If a new item were added to the head of the queue, the adder could set my event so that I could set a new timeout on my sleep.  That may be the way I end up going if I can't come up with a better option.  I just don't want to have to wake up every second and check to see if it's time yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cron is great for scripts run on a regular basis, but if you want a one-off (or two-off) script to run at a particular time you would use the unix 'at' command, and you can do it directly from php using code like this:

```
/****
 * Schedule a command using the AT command
 *
 * To do this you need to ensure that the www-data user is allowed to
 * use the 'at' command - check this in /etc/at.deny
 *
 *
 * EXAMPLE USAGE ::
 *
 * scriptat( '/usr/bin/command-to-execute', 'time-to-run');
 * The time-to-run shoud be in this format: strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", $unixtime)
 *
 **/

function scriptat( $cmd = null, $time = null ) {
    // Both parameters are required
    if (!$cmd) {
        error_log("******* ScriptAt: cmd not specified");
        return false;
    }
    if (!$time) {
        error_log("******* ScriptAt: time not specified");
        return false;
    }

    // We need to locate php (executable)
    if (!file_exists("/usr/bin/php")) {
        error_log("~ ScriptAt: Could not locate /usr/bin/php");
        return false;
    }

    $fullcmd = "/usr/bin/php -f $cmd";

    $r = popen("/usr/bin/at $time", "w");
    if (!$r) {
        error_log("~ ScriptAt: unable to open pipe for AT command");
        return false;
    }
    fwrite($r, $fullcmd);
    pclose($r);

    error_log("~ ScriptAt: cmd=${cmd} time=${time}");

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

soloution 1 :
your php file can include a ultimate loop

```
$con = true;
 while($con)
   {
   //do sample operation
   if($end)
      $con = false;
   else
   sleep(5); // 5 seconds for example
   }
```

soloution 2 :
use cron jobs -- Depend on yout CP you can follow the instruction and call your php program at the specific times 
limit : in  cron job the minimum time between two calling is 1 minute

soloution 3 :
use a shell script and call your php program when ever you want

Comment: I would do a combination of both - keeping a PHP script running forever isn't a good idea. Run the script from the cronjob every 10 minutes, for 10 minutes every time. The script would have a loop that does something like `$start=time(); while (time()-$start < 600) { ... sleep(1); }` and the cronjob would run it every 10 minutes, `*/10 * * * * php /path/to/file`

Comment: You are right , its optional , even we can check the cpu load , if the cpu load was over than what we expected kill the program and wait for the new call (using cronjobs or shell scripting)

Comment: @shesek: I believe that I'm going to go with a combination approach.  The plan will be to limit the minimum amount of time in the future for which one of these timers can be set.  Say, ten minutes.  Then have a cron job that wakes up every two minutes or so and checks to see if a timer is to expire in the next two minutes.  If so, it sleeps until the expiration time, wakes up, and sets off the timer.  Otherwise, it can simply exit from the script knowing that there is no possibility of a new timer being injected.

Comment: Off hand, I know a lot of people have said that PHP can use a lot of resources when it is just sleeping or that it is not good to keep a PHP script running forever (like a daemon).  Does anybody know how many or what kinds of resources this ties up or where the threshold might be for allowing a PHP script to run?

Comment: @William that's an interesting question. I would open that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make PHP [sleep](http://php.net/sleep) for a certain amount of time - it will then resume the code afterwards but this is seriously not recommended because when a script sleeps it still uses up processor resources, and if you had multiple scripts sleeping for long periods of time it would put impossible load on your server.

The only other option that I know of is [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). As @Pete says, you can manage Cron jobs from within PHP, e.g.:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

This is going to involve a fair bit of coding, but I think it is your best options.

Another option is to have your user's browser call a PHP function using an Ajax request and JavaScript's `setTimeout` as suggested by the accepted answer in this question:
[how to call a function in PHP after 10 seconds of the page load (Not using HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333434/how-to-call-a-function-in-php-after-10-seconds-of-the-page-load-not-using-html)