# Date and time scheduling for database operation

Tags: android

I am creating Android project in which I have to perform some database operation through PHP script. 
Normally it is working, but i want to run the PHP script on specific date and time, like creating schedule For some database operation. Is this possible?

Comment: read alarm manager doc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085081/can-a-php-script-be-scheduled-to-run-at-a-specific-time-or-after-a-specific-amou this link may help

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve through AlarmManager class and simple code:

```
Date dateobj = new Date(Year, month, day, hour, min);               
AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateobj.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: how can I perform Database operation here in AlarmManager.i have to pass the value to the phpscript for database operation, by setting schedule