# Restrict a Video online to one view per password, stream only, no download, no repeat

Tags: php, video, passwords, password-protection

I am building a website for a training facility. They would like to sell access to a training video, for ONE TIME viewing.

I am looking for a way to have a simple one-time use generator for access to the page, and restrict after that access 'key' is used. Also to report when it was used and how many times it was attempted to be accessed.

I can 'obscure' the video sufficiently to prevent right-click, or download through conventional means.. but I am struggling with the access to the page itself that hosts the video viewer.

In my mind, it would be a one-time coded url, or generate a unique one-time password, that would expire after first use, and a page expiration after the video is over... but I am not finding any useful url generation utilities to provide that option.

Help? My website is PHP driven, and I have MYSQL or would be ok with flat file as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some thing like this to lock the video in your database

```
Video_id + User_id + is_locked
0001     | 0002    | No
```

After 1st watch

```
-Update db

Video_id + User_id + is_locked
0001     | 0002    | Yes
```

If user tries to access 
Condition :

```
 if Video_id: 0001 and User_id : 0002 and is_locked: Yes
                Unable to access the video
            else
                Show video
                After video shown : Update DB
```

Comment: You know, that's a great idea. I'll investigate that option. ANy ideas on what the trigger would be from the page to lock the user ID after the page has loaded, instead of at the same time? In the case of failed load or delayed page draw?

Comment: @BillieHawkins this might help you to `delay` updating database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333434/how-to-call-a-function-in-php-after-10-seconds-of-the-page-load-not-using-html

Comment: Thanks, may still use this option, if I can't get the PHP wrap to work. Thank you @lemon!

Comment: Old answer but still relevant. So I have a question. When the user gets to see the video the first time, he can copy the URI of the file. Later he can just paste the URI in the browser and access the file. What stops the user from doing this? Or is the idea to implement temporary URLs as well?