# PHP wait before executing script - automatic

Tags: php

Hi so I have a website created from PHP and I want to add a delay onto something so that the script executes after 5 seconds. I want this to be automatic. Here's the snip it of my code that you need to see

```
<div class="banner animated zoomIn">
    <span class="banner">
    <?php include('banner.php'); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Hope I explained this in enough detail, if not then say so and I can reply.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep not enough detail. Can't work out what you're talking about delaying.

Comment: do you mean you want the banner to appear after 5s of delay?

Comment: is this what you mean? `sleep(5)`

Comment: erm - so sort of waiting a certain amount of seconds before executing the script

Comment: maybe sleep(5) but where would I put that in my code?

Comment: at the top of the php script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call a function in PHP after 10 seconds of the page load (Not using HTML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333434/how-to-call-a-function-in-php-after-10-seconds-of-the-page-load-not-using-html)

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra do you mean the top of banner.php?

Comment: I do, but If you want the banner to appear after 5 seconds then using css may be a better approach. otherwise the user will be waiting for 5 seconds for the page to load

Comment: yup taking 5 secs for my page to open now - not sure how to do what i've done in css lol